# How to fit view controller for all iPhones?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I'm working on some apps and I am seriously sad about setting the viewcontroller. Whenever I try my app on different iPhones it looks so fitful. I just want to see my app automatically resized on all iPhones.

I made an example app to explain better.

This is the iPhone 5 screen

[image: iPhone 5]

and this is the iPhone 6S screen
[image: iPhone 6S]

Comment: AutoLayout may be Best for you.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on AutoLayout https://www.appcoda.com/auto-layout-guide/

Comment: SO Documentation on AutoLayout: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/792/auto-layout#t=201610060539210714575

Comment: what was the xcode version u using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to use Autolayout. This is the main tool used to dev UI through all iDevices. Here is a good start :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

You will also need to use size class which use auto layout but allow you to custom your constraints depending on the idevice :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

That's a lot to learn, but believe me, you'll have to use that :)