# Proper way of designing layout dimensions for all the iPhones in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout, interface-builder

I spent hours of searching about this topic, but nothing is exactly dealing with my problem. Maybe you guys can help me better.

I want to ask what is the proper way of designing a layout to properly support all the iPhones. Also the easiest way for me as possible.

My style is that I am designing for the smallest device first and then scale things up for the other devices. Is that alright or is this not how it is supposed to be done?

My problem is that I am creating a layout that should scale up according to display size.

I will give an example of Original iPhone which has screen of 320 x 480 points (which equals 320 x 480 pixels) and iPhone 6, which has screen of 375 x 667 points (which is 750 x 1334 pixels because of the different pixel density).

Now I want to make a button or textbox or rectangle (whatever) on the Original iPhone that will get bigger if I launch it on bigger device like iPhone 6.

So if I have a button having height of 30 (pt) on Original iPhone, it should be bigger on iPhone 6. But how much bigger?

Do I have to calculate those 30 pt into pt on bigger device  myself every time, or is there better method that works automatically so I don't have to re-count all the dimensions for every device? What is the correct way?

Btw: I am aware of that when designing the icons, buttons, or anything that is a .png file, I have to create them in dimensions of 1x, 2x and 3x so it can scale on all the devices, but how to work with these while constructing the actual layout?

What is the logic or how is it ment to be done?

[THIS PICTURE is showing the dimension proportions I found on the web and little bit of idea of my problem below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLaKm.png)

EDIT: Please look at this website: https://designcode.io/iosdesign-guidelines 
It seems like there are some Apple's measurement standarts in (pt).

For example on one of the pictures they are showing that the margin from the sides should be 8pt. Since [pt] is an universal unit, I would expect it to adapt on other devices. So if I set the margin of 8 in editor, will it make different ammount of pixels on the other devices so it looks visually the same?

Comment: Please check out topics on AutoLayout.

Comment: I understand you very well because I had the same problem. The solution is **AutoLayout**. This is the basic thing that you must learn. Please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888238/how-to-fit-view-controller-for-all-iphones

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate every view like this one , it will not work.

Just set constrains on that view which you want same in other devices.

Like if you fix a view's height is 30 then it will 30 in every device. It is not going to be bigger or smaller in other devices.

But if you think that, a view is 20 pixel from right and 20 pixel from left, 10 pixel from top bar and bottom layout then this view gonna same ratio in every device.

I hope you understand what i want too say.

Please comment if i am unable to make you understand. :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I am not sure if we are on the same thing. Please look at this website: https://designcode.io/iosdesign-guidelines 
It seems like there are some Apple's measurement standarts in pt units. For example they say the margins should be 8pt. How to achieve to have exactly 8 pt margin on all devices? Because it looks visually very different if I switch on the bigger/smaller device. Same probelm with text. It doesn't change the size on the different screeen. If I make it in good size on small device, it is totally tiny on bigger device -like if it was in px and not in pt.